# How to install docker version 1.13.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, version

I have Ubuntu 14.04 machine with me and I want to install Docker engine version 1.13.1. I want this version because I want to try docker compose and swarms.

In one of my other machine, I have 1.12.3 available which do not support 'docker stack'. I checked following link for install.

https://docs.docker.com/cs-engine/1.13/#install-on-ubuntu-1404-lts-or-1604-lts

I was able to execute till step number 3. When I check the option to install specifically version 1.13.1 or 1.13.0, it gives me error that no such package is available.

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce=1.13.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce


$ sudo apt-cache madison docker-engine
N: Unable to locate package docker-engine
```

Please help me install 1.13.1.

Thank you.

Comment: docker-ce switched to gentoo versioning. There is no such thing as docker-ce 1.13.1. Do you want the latest docker-ce or do you want 1.13.1? Also, what you tried above conflicts with the documentation you linked to.

Comment: I just want 1.13.1 version

Comment: Then do what the instructions say to do.

Answer (score 0):

Section install from repositories doesn't work well. It seem that version 1.13.xx is not in the repos. 
Issue 
apt-get remove docker-engine
and then follow section [use packages](https://docs.docker.com/cs-engine/1.13/#install-using-packages)

basically it says to download package from [packages-list](https://docs.docker.com/cs-engine/1.13/#package-download-links) and then e.g. sudo dpkg -i docker-engine_1.13.1_cs8-0_ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb